# can't download en model for spaCy 2.0.5 . in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: model, ubuntu-14.04, spacy

I have installed spaCy 2.0.5 using python3 in ubuntu 14.04 .I cant download en model in it.

I tried **python3 -m spacy.en.download** all which showed error saying **error while finding spec for 'spacy.en.download'  no module named 'spacy.en'.**

I have also tried **python3 -m spacy download en** and got the error . I have added the screeenshot of the error.

can someone help me in solving this .[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spacy.en.download` command has been deprecated since v1.7.0 in favour of the new and more flexible [`download` command](https://spacy.io/api/cli#download). This explains the last error you're seeing. So the correct command would definitely be:

```
python3 -m spacy download en
```

If I read your screenshot correctly, I think the true issue here is shown in the error message above, which was produced by pip: `No such option: --no-cache-dir`. Under the hood, spaCy's `download` command uses pip to download and install the models (which are simple Python packages). In order to prevent it from requiring too much memory, it sets the `--no-cache-dir` flag, which requires pip v6.0 or newer. So a likely explanation is that you're using an **outdated version of pip** that doesn't yet support this flag (see the [troubleshooting guide](https://spacy.io/usage/#no-cache-dir) on this topic).

You can run `pip --version` to check the version you have installed, and `pip install -U pip` to upgrade. If you don't want to or can't upgrade pip, you can also download and install the models [manually](https://spacy.io/usage/models#download-pip) by pointing `pip` to the URL of the model file without setting the `--no-cache-dir` flag.